# Create and/or update table in database in Laravel 4 from server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, schema

I am mobile app(Android/iOS) developer, and in the absence of our php developer, I want to add another table in our database and POST and GET some data and store in new table.

Laravel 4 is installed in our server, and with some basic cPanel, phpMyAdmin and php information I tried to create a new table in our existing database.

first I tired and created a table using phpMyAdmin, then I added Model file like this

```
<?php

class Record extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'requestRecords';
protected $guarded = array();
public $timestamps = true;

}
```

But, when i tried add data to `requestRecords`  in my route.php file (which i created manually using phpMyAdmin) using this syntax, nothing happened:

```
Route::post('api/v1/FLRequest', function()
 {

//check right inputs sent to us.
if( !Request::has('userId')     or
    !Request::has('userName')   or
    !Request::has('timeStamp')  or
    !Request::has('requestFor') or
    !Request::has('nKey'))
    return Response::json(array(
        'status' => "error",
        'message' => "Missing Parameter"),
        500
    );


$inputs = Request::all();
if($inputs['nKey']!= "nKey_Goes_Here")
    return Response::json(array(
        'status' => "error",
        'message' => "Wrong Request"),
        500
    );


    $addRecord = Record::create(array(
                                'userName' => $inputs['userName']));

if($addRecord!==FALSE)
{
    return Response::json(array(
        'status' => "success",
        'message' => "Record Updated"),
        200
    );
}
else
{
    return Response::json(array(
        'status' => "error",
        'message' => "Failed Updating Record"),
        401
    );
}
```

Actually I did not get neither 200 nor 401, but I got `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`.

Then I tried adding table using schema, so I created a  php file in database/migrations folder, named: `2015_01_02_104814_create_requestRecords_table.php` and add these codes there :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateRequestRecordsTable extends Migration {

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('requestRecords', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('userId',255);
        $table->string('userName', 255);
        $table->string('timeStamp', 255);
        $table->string('payLoad',255);
        $table->string('requestFor',255);
        $table->string('bToken',255);
        $table->string('bSituation',255);

    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('requestRecords');
}
}
```

and again after trying  to add data, I did not get neither 200 nor 401, but I got `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`.

For more details here is my Controller and Model :

Controller in file `/app/controllers/RequestRecordsController.php`:

```
<?php 
            class RequestRecordsController extends BaseController {

              /**
               * Display a listing of the resource.
               *
               * @return Response
               */
              public function index()
              {

              }

              /**
               * Show the form for creating a new resource.
               *
               * @return Response
               */
              public function create()
              {

              }

              /**
               * Store a newly created resource in storage.
               *
               * @return Response
               */
              public function store()
              {

              }

              /**
               * Display the specified resource.
               *
               * @param  int  $id
               * @return Response
               */
              public function show($id)
              {

              }

              /**
               * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
               *
               * @param  int  $id
               * @return Response
               */
              public function edit($id)
              {

              }

              /**
               * Update the specified resource in storage.
               *
               * @param  int  $id
               * @return Response
               */
              public function update($id)
              {

              }

              /**
               * Remove the specified resource from storage.
               *
               * @param  int  $id
               * @return Response
               */
              public function destroy($id)
              {

              }

            }

            ?>
```

and Model in `/app/models/Record.php` :

```
<?php
class Record extends Eloquent {
protected $table = 'requestRecords';
protected $guarded = array();
public $timestamps = true;

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: Then what response do you get? Just blank? Also, can you make sure the values you don't fill in with `create` are all optional/nullable? Because in your migration they are not.

Comment: @lukasgeiter I got `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Actually I tried creating table with only on column(the only one that I fill in `create`), but again the same 500 Internal Error.

Comment: Please check `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` and update your question with the error message

Comment: @lukasgeiter Actually I remember the day, that our php Developer, said we don't need any logs, and for preventing storage warning, he disabled logging. :((((

Comment: Well that's not so good... Logging should definitely be enabled. Anyways can you turn on debugging in `app/config/app.php` and see if you get a better error message?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thanks! I enabled logging, and here is the error : `[2015-01-02 16:36:40] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migrations' already exists (SQL: create table `migrations` (`migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)' in /home/cafeinst/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:555`

Comment: That really doesn't look like your code is causing this exception. Are you sure you're hitting the right route? Try adding `dd('test'` to the very beginning of your controller method. You should get `string(4) "test"` as response.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thanks again, after adding  dd('test') to my controller, nothing changed, but after adding it to my model, I got response `string(4) "test"`.

Comment: Can you update your question with the full controller method and the route you are calling please?

Comment: Oh I thought you did `Record::create` etc in the controller? Where do you have this code? Directly in the route?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Yes. I have it directly in route in `/app/routes.php`. I Updated my question again with complete route file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68083/discussion-between-lukasgeiter-and-reza-rg).

Answer (score 0):

You are adding lots of validation and always throwing a 500 error yourself on the application.

A best practice would be for you to remove all of that, try to make things work first, and after that. When you see that the code works, then you add validation to make sure that every field you want is on the form.